# How to inject bower dependency in right order to jhipster project

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, jhipster, gulp-inject

I am trying to inject [ngmap](https://ngmap.github.io/) to my jhipster project. After installation dependency with

> bower install ngmap --save

it appears in my bower.json file :

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "myApp",
  "appPath": "src/main/webapp/",
  "testPath": "src/test/javascript/spec",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-aria": "1.5.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "1.3.3",
    "angular-cache-buster": "0.4.3",
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
    "angular-dynamic-locale": "0.1.32",
    "angular-i18n": "1.5.8",
    "ngstorage": "0.3.10",
    "angular-loading-bar": "0.9.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.8",
    "angular-translate": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.11.1",
    "angular-translate-storage-cookie": "2.11.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker": "2.4.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "json3": "3.3.2",
    "messageformat": "0.3.1",
    "modernizr": "3.3.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "12.0.4",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.3.0",
    "swagger-ui": "2.1.5",
    "arrive": "2.3.0",
    "bootstrap-material-design": "0.5.10",
    "ngmap": "^1.17.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.8"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "angular": {
      "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "3.1.0"
      }
    },
    "angular-cache-buster": {
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8"
      }
    },
    "angular-dynamic-locale": {
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8"
      }
    },
    "bootstrap-sass": {
      "main": [
        "assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Gulp injects ngmap BEFORE angular dependency:

```
<script src="bower_components/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

what occurs with error :

> ng-map.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
>
> app.module.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(…)

I've injected js file to the index.html manually, on the end of the file. It works locally, on my development environment, but after deploy to heroku, the same error as above occurs. How can I force gulp to inject it in right order?

It's my gulpfile.js:

```
// Generated on 2016-10-20 using generator-jhipster 3.9.1
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    expect = require('gulp-expect-file'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    flatten = require('gulp-flatten'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    del = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handle-errors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    copy = require('./gulp/copy'),
    inject = require('./gulp/inject'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');

var config = require('./gulp/config');

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return del([config.dist], { dot: true });
});

gulp.task('copy', ['copy:i18n', 'copy:fonts', 'copy:common']);

gulp.task('copy:i18n', copy.i18n);

gulp.task('copy:languages', copy.languages);

gulp.task('copy:fonts', copy.fonts);

gulp.task('copy:common', copy.common);

gulp.task('copy:swagger', copy.swagger);

gulp.task('copy:images', copy.images);

gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/images/**')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 5, progressive: true, interlaced: true}))
        .pipe(rev())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist + 'content/images'))
        .pipe(rev.manifest(config.revManifest, {
            base: config.dist,
            merge: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return es.merge(
        gulp.src(config.sassSrc)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(expect(config.sassSrc))
        .pipe(changed(config.cssDir, {extension: '.css'}))
        .pipe(sass({includePaths:config.bower}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.cssDir)),
        gulp.src(config.bower + '**/fonts/**/*.{woff,woff2,svg,ttf,eot,otf}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.app + 'content/fonts'))
        .pipe(flatten())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'content/fonts'))
    );
});

gulp.task('styles', ['sass'], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'content/css')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('inject', function() {
    runSequence('inject:dep', 'inject:app');
});

gulp.task('inject:dep', ['inject:test', 'inject:vendor']);

gulp.task('inject:app', inject.app);

gulp.task('inject:vendor', inject.vendor);

gulp.task('inject:test', inject.test);

gulp.task('inject:troubleshoot', inject.troubleshoot);

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html', 'copy:swagger', 'copy:images'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'myApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:dev', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'myApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: true
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'myApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: false
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('test', ['inject:test', 'ngconstant:dev'], function (done) {
    new KarmaServer({
        configFile: __dirname + '/' + config.test + 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
    }, done).start();
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'pom.xml'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.sassSrc, ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject:app']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['inject:dep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'sass', 'copy:languages', 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot');
});

gulp.task('serve', ['install'], serve);

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'inject:vendor', 'ngconstant:prod', 'copy:languages'], 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot', 'assets:prod', cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

inject.js :

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    es = require('event-stream'),
    naturalSort = require('gulp-natural-sort'),
    angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort'),
    bowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

var handleErrors = require('./handle-errors');

var config = require('./config');

module.exports = {
    app: app,
    vendor: vendor,
    test: test,
    troubleshoot: troubleshoot
}

function app() {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
            .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
            .pipe(naturalSort())
            .pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
}

function vendor() {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles(), {read: false}), {
            name: 'bower',
            relative: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));

    return es.merge(stream, gulp.src(config.sassVendor)
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles({filter:['**/*.{scss,sass}']}), {read: false}), {
            name: 'bower',
            relative: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scss)));
}

function test() {
    return gulp.src(config.test + 'karma.conf.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(bowerFiles({includeDev: true, filter: ['**/*.js']}), {read: false}), {
            starttag: '// bower:js',
            endtag: '// endbower',
            transform: function (filepath) {
                return '\'' + filepath.substring(1, filepath.length) + '\',';
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.test));
}

function troubleshoot() {
    /* this task removes the troubleshooting content from index.html*/
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        /* having empty src as we dont have to read any files*/
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src('', {read: false}), {
            starttag: '<!-- inject:troubleshoot -->',
            removeTags: true,
            transform: function () {
                return '<!-- Angular views -->';
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to add this in overrides in bower.json:

```
"overrides": {
    "ngmap": {
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8"
      }
    }
 }
```

Regards!